# EasyPHP default load page

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I've noticed that when I access *local web* the default `index.php` file in the `www` folder doesn't show, and when I open a folder it automatically opens the file with name `index.html`, anyone knows why that is happening? (I'm using *EasyPHP 1.8* because it's the version we're using in high school).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208930/when-to-use-index-php-instead-of-index-html

Comment: not my question

Comment: @DEarTh - that question has little / nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @Adam Check out the accepted answer.

Comment: @Adam Check out the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the *web server* configuration you're using.

Set in *apache2* configuration file (for example in *Ubuntu 16.04* `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`) or in `.htaccess` file (that will give priority to `.php` file over `.html` file):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

or simply:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, more precisely I was looking to know if easyphp specifically opened the file named "index" and I got my answer I guess.